# `Error: MLIR Pass Manager Failed': TensorFlow on MacBook Pro M1 Max

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I'm running Python 3.9.7 and TensorFlow 2.5 on my MacBook Pro with M1 Max chip, in a virtual environment managed through MiniForge. (Setup due to [Jeff Heaton](https://github.com/jeffheaton/t81_558_deep_learning/blob/master/install/tensorflow-install-mac-metal-jul-2021.ipynb)).

I have a custom loss function in the model. This code runs fine on my other machine, which is Ubuntu-based Pop!OS.

When I run model.fit from Keras, I **occasionally** get the following errors. Sometimes it runs just fine. Any idea what's causing it, why it only happens sometimes, and how to fix it?

In addition, it only produces this error from my custom loss function. Not from any Keras-native.

Thanks!

```
:5:10: error: invalid length (0) for size 20                                                                                                                             | 0.00/1.00 [00:00<?, ?batch/s]
-:5:10: error: 'mps.slice' op failed to fold or infer return types
-:5:10: note: see current operation: %2 = "mps.slice"(%arg0) {axis = 0 : si32, length = 999 : i32, start = 1 : i32} : (tensor<20xf32>) -> tensor<*xf32>
/System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/5b2e67f8af/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/MetalPerformanceShadersGraph/MetalPerformanceShadersGraph-2.2.1/mpsgraph/MetalPerformanceShadersGraph/Core/Files/MPSGraphExecutable.mm:1179: failed assertion `Error: MLIR pass manager failed'
model.fit(tf.convert_to_tensor(Σ),tf.zeros((T,output)),batch_size=T,epochs=1,verbose=0,callbacks=[TqdmCallback()])#,tbc])
zsh: abort      python3
(tensorflow) kpmott@kevins-mbp-7 tf.olg % model.fit(tf.convert_to_tensor(Σ),tf.zeros((T,output)),batch_size=T,epochs=1,verbose=0,callbacks=[TqdmCallback()])#,tbc])
zsh: parse error near `)'
(tensorflow) kpmott@kevins-mbp-7 tf.olg % /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:216: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '
model.fit(tf.convert_to_tensor(Σ),tf.zeros((T,output)),batch_size=T,epochs=1,verbose=0,callbacks=[TqdmCallback()])#,tbc])
zsh: parse error near `)'
```

Comment: Hi PaulMest! Could you set up a new environment and test with [Metal plugin](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/)  instructions  and TF 2.11 to see whether issue persists.  Please  provide a sample stand alone code for further assistance.